# Interchange of two words of same column In R

Tags: r

I had a file in which one column contains two words and I want to swap these two words.

```
str_split(d$brand," ")
d$brand<-  cbind(unlist(str_split(d$brand," "))[2],unlist(str_split(d$brand," "))[1])
```

Comment: That's ok, but what is your question? Did you get stuck somewhere? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi,In a dataset I had a column containing two words like Adidas India and I want to change it like India Adidas.

Comment: While executing the code got a error Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "CountryBrand", value = c("RP", "Adidas" : replacement has 1 row, data has 3503 –